# Letters Don't Display Correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am on linux mint 19 cinnamon. I am trying to use vscode, but the letters are all mangled and unreadable, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1u6.png). Can anyone help me fix this? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [current](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46879) [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35644) with fonts, you can try and change the [VSCode fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29960057/6309) with:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Courier New'"
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'DejaVu Sans Mono'"
```

And see if the situation improves.

Or: see [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21559#issuecomment-290980784):

> For me at least, this was solved by first viewing the user settings (`File>Preferences>Settings`), and when I added `editor.fontFamily` to the object I found the default settings out, which were:
>
> ```
> "editor.fontFamily": 
>    "'Droid Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'",
> ```
>
> As I'm running Linux Mint I don't believe this distro or Ubuntu carry Droid Sans Mono by default any more, so I simply downloaded it [from Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Droid%20Sans%20Mono) and installed it via the normal means.
>
> Restarted VS Code and voila! Nice fonts again.