# How to Set the Font of the Python Interactive Window?

Tags: python, fonts, visual-studio-code

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Visual Studio Code.

Is there a way to change the font of the `Out` cells in the [Python Interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support)?

The current font is `Courier New` and it's annoying.

I've tried to override it by installing the fonts `Inconsolata` and `Droid Sans Mono` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960057/which-font-is-used-in-visual-studio-code-editor-and-how-to-change-fonts) and similar posts.

It resulted with replacing `Courier New` in the Debug area and Markdown preview but **not** in the Python Interactive window.

When I uninstall `Courier New`, it finally falls to (I think) `Liberation Mono`.

I'd like to find the way to set a desired font for the `Out` cells in the Python Interactive window without unistalling fonts.