# Letter M is invisible in Visual Studio Code in MacOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

Using the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code on MacOS, it seems the letter M is invisible most of the time. Not all, but most of the time. Here's a screenshot below of my terminal.

[image]

When I attempt to copy the text from the terminal, I am able to paste all the letters just fine including the letter M.

Also, this is just happening within the integrated terminal for VSCode. The system terminal works fine and shows all the letters.

Comment: What happens if you change typefaces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960057/which-font-is-used-in-visual-studio-code-editor-and-how-to-change-fonts

If you have a corrupted font cache, you could try deleting that cache: https://gist.github.com/jaredhowland/2da83f0cc0fbb1ac523f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned off GPU acceleration for the terminal in the Settings. That seemed to have fixed it.

[image: Setting in VSCode]