# Is it possible to change Python font in Visual Studio Code to cursive?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, fonts

I'm sorry if this is a question already answered or if this kind of questions are not allowed.

I have been trying to figure out how to change the font (cursive like `Fira Code iScript`) in VS Code for Python like people have done for HTML and other languages to make it look prettier.
[image]

#### Attempts and Research

I spent last 3 hours to figure this out and watched multiple tutorials, but nothing seems to work for me. Now I have doubts that if it even works for Python in VS code.

I watched multiple tutorials on YouTube and other websites to figure it out but it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does this help you [Which font is used in Visual Studio Code Editor and how to change fonts? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960057/which-font-is-used-in-visual-studio-code-editor-and-how-to-change-fonts) ?

Comment: Although this is possible, it is not necessarily smart.  The default monospace fonts are chosen for their readability.  That cursive font is provably harder to read than a sans serif font.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your Syntax Highlighting theme. Either find the one that already has this text stylized or edit your current one to do it.

The parameter you need to set in there is called `"fontStyle"` and you need to set it as `"italic"` for all entities you want. You can find more about it in the Visual Studio Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)

This sounds difficult but it's not really, just bit time consuming. Fastest way would be of course finding a theme that already has it set though :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the font through `editor: Font Family` in the **Settings**

[image]

or add the following configuration in *settings.json*.

```json
    "editor.fontFamily": "Ink Free,Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
```

[image]

*The configuration content needs to be modified to the font name you need.*