# How can I tell what fonts are ACTUALLY being used in VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fedora

In VSCode (specifically on Fedora), how can I tell what fonts are actually being used by the system in the terminal (or anywhere else)?

I am aware that there are options in settings.json to set things like "terminal.integrated.fontFamily". But that will only tell me what font(s) are configured for use, not which one is actually being used.

Comment: open Developer Tools and inspect the elements of interest (use locater in top left) and analyze the CSS used

Comment: in particular, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605449/11107541