# How to change the interface font in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the font of the interface in VSCode?
I am most interested in the font of folder and file names.

[image]

Comment: search settings for `font` and see if there is a setting for the GUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which font is used in Visual Studio Code Editor and how to change fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960057/which-font-is-used-in-visual-studio-code-editor-and-how-to-change-fonts)

Comment: @rioV8 I did not find it, there you can change the FontFamily of the terminal and the editor itself, but not the names of the files

Comment: @lchristmann I mean the FontFamily of the interface, not the code editor.

Comment: you can change the CSS style of anything in VSC by using the `CSS Inject` extension